# Running Docker from a Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-machine

Doing a project for my dissertation which involves an angular frontend which talks to a node API backend which needs to use docker to create containers from images run a few lines of code for the console output.

I have used docker-compose to create two docker containers for my frontend & backend.

my backend (api) container needs a way to connect to docker using [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) and I'm not sure how to do this.

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3001:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/code
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
```

I have tried :

1 using docker-machine on my host (windows 10) but whenever I try to connect from the docker container (backend) via [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) 'ReferenceError: docker is not defined' but am unsure if docker-machine is running correctly on my host as I'm on windows 10 using hyper-v.

```
const docker = new Docker({host: 'http://192.168.0.23', port: 3000});
```

2 installing docker into the docker container which has failed every time and when successfully installed it won't recognize 'docker' as running on the system.

3 adding the docker image to the docker-compose file as I thought could that work? for me, no but don't know if that's because of the networking of not the intended use for the docker image

```
  docker:
   image: docker
   ports: 
    - "2376:2376"
   stdin_open: true
   tty: true
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I am fairly new to docker especially the networking side and have been looking at things like docker-machine, docker-swarm & Kubernetes to find the best solution.

any insight into this would be greatly appreciated as the biggest hurdle for this project is getting my backend API to talk with docker in a deployed environment.

Comment: your question is not clear,but i think you need `docker:dind` image. https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/92d278e671f32a9ee4a3c0668e46a41f4a3b74b0/19.03/dind/Dockerfile

Comment: anything I can clear up about the question? I tried adding the dind image to my docker composer but still, get 'docker is undefined '. I added it as 'docker' exposed port 2376 and tried to connect from my API using Docker({host: 'http://docker', port: 2376});

Comment: What do you mean by being unable to connect with Docker? Are you trying to run your frontend and backend images from within another container?

Comment: iv updated my question to include my docker-compose.yml and a bit more detail above it. in short I want to connect my backend container to docker using dockerode somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for everyone but adding dind to my project worked for what I need.

```
docker-in-docker:
  image: docker:dind
  environment:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  privileged: true
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/docker
  expose:
    - 2375
    - 2376
```

and for any container in docker-compose that will connect to "docker-in-docker" needs this in their service. the "DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR" is to remove TLS

```
  links:
    - docker-in-docker
  environment:
    DOCKER_HOST: http://docker-in-docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

another note for anyone using dockerode, when using async & await just on my local was fine but I would always get docker is undefined once moving it to a docker environment which can be fixed by using .then instead.